# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null in ANDROID

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

```
                       <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: No tab known for tag null.By this error cannot get Preview in Android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error due to the tab fragment not available . please change your API version(gradle file change api version) to that are available in your studio. after change this click the reload button in the preview section

Answer (score 0):

if this error is showing xml perview 
 check your android version api if this one is 23 do it 22 or 21 according to android sdk lib